# @font-face not loading in react app (storybook)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, fonts, storybook

I am having trouble in loading fonts from local and I am pointing to the directory. Can someone help me with it ?

Here is my code

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'My font';
  src: url('./fonts/Myfonts-webfont.eot');
  src: url('./fonts/Myfonts-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('./fonts/Myfonts-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('./fonts/Myfonts-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('./fonts/Myfonts-webfont.svg#my_fonts_otbook') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

and using it as 
.btn {
  font-family: 'My font', sans-serif;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 8%;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error when I load my application, sans-serif fonts are loading instead of My font.

Comment: When I build my app I am getting performance warnings from webpack

Comment: Assets:
   font/myfonts-Book.ttf (315 KiB)
   font/myfonts-Semibold.ttf (257 KiB)
   vendors~main.aa2cd040f0c1fba7504e.bundle.js (1.52 MiB)
entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest having a look at this

Also depending where you have them stored i.e. assets/fonts you must be pointing towards the directory.

[font-face syntax](https://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/)

Example

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Graublau Web';
  src: url('GraublauWeb.eot');
  src: local('☺︎'),
    url("GraublauWeb.woff") format("woff"),
    url("GraublauWeb.otf") format("opentype"),
    url("GraublauWeb.svg#grablau") format("svg");
}
```

Comment: I am using the same syntax forgot to wrap it in @font-face{.......}  while posting here

Answer (score 0):

I tried different things and finally able to find the issue. its the storybook web-pack config causing the issue. Instead of pushing module.rules to storybook default webpack config I overwrote rules and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you use webpack file-loader to load a path, you dont have to specify where you font files reside. As long as you include your font files inside src/assets/fonts, file-loader will find it for you.